# Remove default alpha blending in legend key, change legend key titles

Tags: r, plot, legend, alpha

I have a visual of three different groups, that I have made into a scatterplot:

```
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,0,1), y=rnorm(1000,0,1), 
                 cluster=sample(1:3, 1000,replace=TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cluster)), alpha=0.3) + 
xlab("My x-axis") + 
ylab("My y-axis") + 
theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
theme(legend.text =element_text("Clusters")) + 
ggtitle("My title")
```

The only things I could not get had to do with the legend (at the bottom). I want to remove the current default text "factor(cluster") and, instead, hardcode in a text for each group. For instance, I have a pink, green, and blue dots in my legend, so I could hardcode something like `c("Pink group", "Green group", "Blue group")`. The second thing I cannot fix is the way that the legend colors are automatically also alpha blended. I want them to be their full colors.

(I played around with this second problem, and when I moved the `alpha=0.3` into the `aes()` function, then the legend colors were full... but I had an unwanted new second legend for alpha levels, as shown below):

```
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,0,1), y=rnorm(1000,0,1), 
                 cluster=sample(1:3, 1000,replace=TRUE))

ggplot(dat,aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cluster),alpha=0.3)) + 
xlab("My x-axis") + 
ylab("My y-axis") + 
theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
theme(legend.text =element_text("Clusters")) + 
ggtitle("My title")
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

I tried as one user lukeA suggested. The user said it worked on their side, but for me, the color of the keys did become full, but their text was absent. There was no individual text next to any of the three circles, and there was the unwanted term "New Text" by it as well.

```
dat=data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,0,1),y=rnorm(1000,0,1),cluster=sample(1:3, 1000,replace=TRUE))
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x,y))+geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cluster),alpha=0.3))+xlab("My x-axis")+ylab("My y-axis")+theme(legend.position="bottom")+ theme(legend.text =element_text("Clusters"))+ggtitle("My title")
p + labs(colour = "New Text") + scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("Pink group", "Green group", "Blue group")) + guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

I also tried:

```
dat=data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,0,1),y=rnorm(1000,0,1),cluster=sample(1:3, 1000,replace=TRUE))
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x,y))+geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cluster),alpha=0.3))+xlab("My x-axis")+ylab("My y-axis")+theme(legend.position="bottom")+ theme(legend.text =element_text("Clusters"))+ggtitle("My title")
p + labs(colour = "New Text") + scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("1"="Pink  group", "2"="Green group", "3"="Blue group")) + guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

which only changed by having numbers associated in c("1"="Pink group", "2"="Green group", "3"="Blue group"). This also led to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
p <- ggplot(dat,aes(x,y))+geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cluster),alpha=0.3))+xlab("My x-axis")+ylab("My y-axis")+theme(legend.position="bottom")+ theme(legend.text =element_text("Clusters"))+ggtitle("My title")
p + labs(colour = "New Text") + 
  scale_colour_discrete(labels = c("1" = "Pink group", "2"= "Green group", "3" = "Blue group")) + 
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. It did seem to fix the alpha-blending problem! However, each of the three dots in the legend did not have their labels "Pink group", "Green group", and "Blue group". They were still simply blank. I wonder if there is something causing us to get differences? I ran exactly what you wrote, only preceded by dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000,0,1), y=rnorm(1000,0,1), 
                 cluster=sample(1:3, 1000,replace=TRUE)). And I cleared all variables in my workspace beforehand too...

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce the error using ggplot 1.0.1. Try an unnamed vector like `c("Pink group", "Green group", "Blue group")`.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post to include the exact code that I used. (Just to make sure we are on the same page).